# Ссылка на класс из статического метода

Tags: python, python-2.x

Всем привет.
Есть такой класс-контейнер

```
class Container:

    class Menu:
        a = 2
        b = 4

        @staticmethod
        def get_a():
            return a
```

`return a` разумеется не работает. 
`return Menu.a` не работает.
`return __class__.a` тоже не работает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно получить доступ к переменным класса `Menu`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь не статическим методом, а методом класса. Это почти тоже самое, что и статический, только он еще принимает ссылку на класс. Оберните вашу функцию декоратором `@classmethod`, и вы сможете достучаться к его атрибутам:

```
@classmethod
def get_a(cls):
    return cls.a
```

Передавать ссылку на класс не нужно, это происходит автоматически:

```
a = Menu.get_a()
```